# Is it possible to reverse the start and end point of a substring?

Tags: java, string, methods, substring

So in genereal the set-up for substring is something like:

```
s.substring(beginIndex, EndIndex);
```

Is it possible to switch it to:

```
s.substring(EndIndex, BeginIndex);
```

Thanks!

Comment: No thats the way it provided in the API

Comment: What do you think ? Why not ? You will have to write code for that but its possible

Comment: Do you want the substring to be reversed, or are you just looking for a method with the two parameters reversed? If so, what for?

Comment: sure, just reverse your string before passing it in...

Comment: I can't see why you would, but if you really have to switch the two arguments, perhaps you can do `s.reverse().substring(EndIndex, BeginIndex).reverse()`. Not that I would ever do that..

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the class and the method:

```
public class StringInMyWorld {
    private final String horribleString;
    // + constructor, getter

    public String iDoNothingLikeEverybodyElse(int endIndex, 
                                              int beginIndex) {
        return horribleString.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one that provided in the code. You could use s.reverse() to get the string in backwards. Then you would can use normal substring yet the begin index will be at the end and vice versa. Then, if you want it to go back in the correct order you can use s.reverse() again.

Comment: Killing the performance by reversing the entire/majority of string twice when only first and last part needed to be swapped ....

Comment: He didn't say that he only wanted the first and last char to be swapped. He wants to know if you could get a substring of a string backwards

Answer (score 0):

Use the String.substring method to get the characters excluding the first and last letter, then concatenating the beginning and end characters at the required position.

EG:

```
 firstChar=yourString.subString(0,1) 
 lastChar=yourString.subString(yourString.length-1,yourString.length)
 yourInBetweenString=yourString.subString(1,yourString.length-1)
 yourNewString=lastChar+ yourInBetweenString+ firstChar
```

Something on these lines.